# Positioning an element w.r.t the window using jquery

Tags: jquery, offset

```
var wdt = document.body.offsetWidth/2.6

var hgt = document.body.offsetHeight/4

$("#element").offset({left:wdt, top:hgt})
```

what i am trying to do is position the image(#element) relative to the body..ie to the center with respect to the window ... for different Browser/window sizes/screen....irrespective of any screen.

Is this valid.. or are there any more..?

Comment: With regard to your variable names, you should keep them fairly verbose; 'wdt' means nothing to any other developers besides you, whereas 'width', though only a few characters longer, is *much* more readable.

Comment: Agreed. That makes sense.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#element").css({left:50%, top:50%});
```

or

```
$("#element").css({left:window.innerWidth/2.6, top:window.innerHeight/4});
```

Should do it. Or better yet, in your CSS file:

```
#element {
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
}
```

Be aware that this will position your element based on the upper left corner, so it won't appear to be in the exact center. To account for that, you could do this (keeping the above CSS):

```
$("#element").offset({
    left:-$(this).css("width")/2,
    top:-$(this).css("height")/2
});
```

Comment: This cannot position the element correctly, as element size is not accounted for

Comment: @Vinay: See the bottom of my answer, it should take care of everything for you automatically.

Comment: Cool, Will implement this and let u know.. :) Appreciate your help all :)

Comment: That goes without saying.
Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery

```
$("img").css({
  top: ($(window).height()-$("img").height())/2,
  margin: '0 auto'
});
```

Comment: Don't forget he wants the top in the center as well. Or, to be precise, 25% of the way down.

Comment: Don't know what you're talking about-- I *did* update my answer.